# Невозможно обработать повисшую символьную ссылку

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu

Поставил phpmyadmin.

`sudo tasksel install lamp-server
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/phpmyadmin`

Выдает chmod: невозможно обработать повисшую символьную ссылку «`/var/www/phpmyadmin`»

Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Наверное потому что это символьная ссылка